# title background with scss

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve this via scss

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55fuE.png)

a title with a clored background

I tried  adding : before with colored bacground
and also I tried making one div relative and the other one position: aboslute
b ut it didn't work

html:

```
`    <div class="volunteer__title">
          <div class="volunteer__title--bg">      
          <div class="volunteer__title--text" >Volunteer</div>
      </div>`
```

css:

```
 &__title {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;

    &--bg {
      background-color: $darkGreen;
      width: 100px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      &--text {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

but didn't work
any ideas?

Comment: Your CSS appears to be sass, as you tagged the question, please could you share the relevant CSS generated from your sass? Also, I've removed the saas tag as this doesn't appear relevant at all.

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean, it's saas but saas tag is not relevant?

Comment: [tag:Sass] is relevant, [saas](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/saas/info) is - as the link points out - "software as a service," which doesn't seem to be at all relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @001 was on the right track, there are some changes to be made to add responsivness and to simplyfy the entire case.

First at all you should not use an HTML element to create the green box but a pseudo-element by using either `::before` ore `::after` and then position it with `position: absolute` in relative units.

```css
.volunteer__title {
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.volunteer__title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #8FD192;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  right: -0.1em;
  width: 6.7ch;
  height: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="volunteer__title">    
    <div class="volunteer__title--text" >volunteer</div>
</div>
```

If you want it in SASS you can use combi9ne it into:

```scss
.volunteer__title {
  font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  font-weight: 500;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #8FD192;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.4em;
    right: -0.1em;
    width: 6.7ch;
    height: 0.7em;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    z-index: -1; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a change using `display` property, from `fixed` to `absolute`.

**Fixed Positioning:**
 When an element is set to `position: fixed;` it is positioned relative to the browser window's viewport, regardless of scrolling. This means that even if the user scrolls the page, the element will stay in the same position on the screen. Fixed elements are often used for headers, footers, or navigation bars that need to remain visible at all times.

**Absolute Positioning:**
On the other hand, when an element is set to `position: absolute;` it is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (an element with a position value other than static) or the document's initial containing block if no positioned ancestor is found. Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal document flow, allowing you to precisely position it anywhere on the page. When the page is scrolled, absolute positioned elements will move with their positioned ancestor.

I mixed `display: absolute;` and `z-index: -1;` (check the code below).

Check `width: fit-content` in `volunteer__title` as well.

### Example 1

```css
.volunteer__title {
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.volunteer__title--bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8FD192;
  width: 116px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 6px;
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="volunteer__title">
    <div class="volunteer__title--bg"></div>      
    <div class="volunteer__title--text" >volunteer</div>
</div>
```

In SCSS:

```
.volunteer__title {
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    font-weight: 500;

    &--bg {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #8FD192;
        width: 116px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top: 6px;
        right: -3px;
    }
}
```

### Example 2

In this example, I get rid of the element `bg` and used `::after` that creates a pseudo-element of the selected element (`text`).

```css
.volunteer__title {
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.volunteer__title--text::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8FD192;
  width: 116px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 6px;
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="volunteer__title">
    <div class="volunteer__title--text" >volunteer</div>
</div>
```

In SCSS:

```
.volunteer__title {
    font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    font-weight: 500;

    &--text::after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #8FD192;
        width: 116px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top: 6px;
        right: -3px;
    }
}
```

For more details about these properties, check the links below:

[CSS Tricks | Absolute, Relative, Fixed Positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) 
[MDN | z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) 
[MDN | ::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)